# What is a transactions obsoleteTag used for?

Tags: transaction, bundles, optional-tag

Why is there a `tag` and `obsoleteTag` in a transaction? In the code, I could find one usage ([iota.lib.js](https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.lib.js/blob/0927cdd94f496ca1939d0b885a6b513a0b8c5aa5/lib/crypto/bundle/bundle.js#L122)) of the obsoleteTag being incremented if the normalized hash is considered insecure. This implies that one can't be sure that the obsoleteTag, or a small part of it, changes during bundle creation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*obsoleteTag* will be removed soon. The preliminary final design of the bundle essence fragment is:

> extraDataDigest [243 trits]
>
> address [243 trits]
>
> value [81 trits]
>
> issuanceTimestamp [27 trits]
>
> timelockLowerBound [27 trits]
>
> timelockUpperBound [27 trits]
>
> bundleNonce [81 trits]

Now that part contains *obsoleteTag*.

Comment: Is there any documentation which covers these changes?

Comment: No documentation, the changes haven't been tested yet.

Comment: What is the bundleNonce? POW nonce?

Comment: No, PoW nonce is in another place of the transactions. *bundleNonce* replaces Winternitz checksum.

Comment: @Come-from-Beyond Is there a reference or document with the final design?